# turf.centerOfMass for multiple polygons in Feature Collection

Tags: javascript, turfjs

I am having trouble with getting the data for turf.centerOfMass() correct.

I have a featureCollection which can have multiple polygons added to it.

```
var polygonlines = [];
//add to polygons etc..
    if (polygonlines.length >= 4) {
                    var feature =
                    {
                        "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [polygonlines] }
                    }
    
                    features.push(feature);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    var featCollection = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: features
    }
```

I want to calculate the centroid, center and the centerOfMass.

```
var centroid = turf.centroid(featCollection); //WORKS CORRECTLY
var centre = turf.center(featCollection); //WORKS CORRECTLY

var centreofMass = turf.centerOfMass(featCollection);  //FAILS
```

The centerOfMass calculation fails and give me the error:
"Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Qt is not a constructor"

The only way i can get centerOfMass to not fail is to list an individual polygon from the featcollection... but this is not what i want, i want the center for multiple polygons. The turf documentation says centerOfMass can take a FeatureCollection, centre and centroid do and they work fine...

How do I get it to get the centerOfMass for multiple polygons?

Thank you very much